# CSS image constraints/resizing

Tags: html, css, image

I've been making a tumblr theme using html/css and it allows the user to input their own image that will show up in their sidebar on the theme.

I'm not sure how to constrain the image to a certain region/size on the screen. What I have right now for the css of the image (which is probably excessive)

```
.sidebaricon {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

But when I upload differently sized photos they don't constrain to the same size. I want all the uploaded images to constrain to a 500x500px square region. 
Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Can we see a live example of your tumblr theme ?

Comment: It's very rough since I started it like 30 minutes ago haha. jotest.tumblr.com I uploaded an image so it's easier to see. I want the image to be constrained before changing stuff around with it

Comment: Do the images constrain at all? Or are they larger than 500px?

Comment: I think they constrain somewhat because earlier I had a larger image that filled up the page and when I changed the css around it was smaller. I want all images to fit into a same size box, though. It doesn't have to be 500px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you try to upload an image and set it a max width. There's some mistakes in your code and some things that can be confusing (e.g. : your sidebar and its image have the same class).

First you need to set a width to your sidebar:

```
.sidebar  { /* I renamed the container to avoid any misunderstanding */
    width: 30%; /* or whatever */
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Then, the image in the sidebar :

```
    .sidebar .sidebaricon { /* this should be your img */
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

*The logic is quite simple : you let the image to fill 100% of its parent's width, so you just have to play with the parent's width.*

A lot of CSS frameworks use the same technic to provide a quick way to make all images "responsive", like this :

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Again, this means : all images in the document body should have a maximum width of **100% of its container**. I added the automatic height as some old IE doesn't keep the ratio by default.